# Windows 10 : Windows seems to create an empty Local drive after boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtual-drive

My Windows 10 creates an empty (size 0) Drive (Q:, seen as a local drive), on which I have no access right, even as Administrator.

When I go in This Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Manager this Disk does not appear.

This does not occur when I restart in Safe Mode.

Only 2 Avast Softwares are Enabled on Boot in the Task Manager.

Any idea what kind of Program could be creating an empty virtual Hard drive at Boot ?

May be Related : I also have a "How do you want to open this Program" that I can't fix, because I have nothing more than the above enabled at boot so I don't understand where the problem come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q: drive is the virtual file system drive where virtualized applications are located in the file system namespace. This Q: drive is not a typical drive. The Q: drive has no space that the user can access directly and is inaccessible from Windows Explorer or My Computer.

This drive does not show up as a result of Windows 10, nor is it a Windows problem. Instead, **this drive appears when a Click-to-Run version of Microsoft Office 2010 is installed**.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982434/an-overview-of-microsoft-office-click-to-run-for-office-2010

Comment: I believe that if the MS Office package is left installed, there is information in the volume name to indicate this, while if the factory-supplied try-before-you-by program is removed, the identifier is removed/

Comment: I looked for everything except the exact letter of the drive since it can be changed... thank you!